# SQLite database download

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to download database (SQLite) which has to be used in app. Before saving the downloaded data, which comes as NSData, I want to check if the downloaded data is an SQLite database. How can I check.

For example:

The correct URLl of the database is http://example.com/mydatabase.db

If somehow URL is typed as http://example.com/mydatabase.bdx, which does not exist, I still receive some data in NSData.

```
NSData *dbfile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://example.com/mydatabase.db"]];
```

I surely can check after saving file and trying to open and if it fails to open it is having some problem. But I would like to check in NSData without the need to save the file if correct data is not downloaded.

How can I check without saving?

Comment: compare url-strings using isEqualToString

Comment: it is not just about correct or incorrect url. Because if some day database name changed, then still you receive something in NSData. I want to verify either the correct file downloaded 'mydatabase.db' or contents of NSData if it is a sqlite db.

Comment: see.. to check if it is correct filename or not? there should be some base for comparison. eg.do u want to check the extension of file(.db->correct OR .bdx->incorrect)? If u could tell me on what basis u decide if the file is correct or not; then I could help u a bit..!

Comment: yes.. if the file extension is .db and the size of file (which will be fixed) then I can consider it correct otherwise not.

Comment: Because I dont know how to check if NSData contains which type of data. If I need to save the NSData as file, then it is alternative solution. I would like to check in NSData variable if it downloaded correct data. Because NSData can also download .html (in case of wrong url) and also .db in case of correct url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through [the sqlite3 interface documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/intro.html), all I can find is [`sqlite3_open()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) and friends, which all take a filename, rather than a chunk of data.

Thus, short of shipping your own custom sqlite3 library, I think you're going to have to save your downloaded `NSData` as you describe - dump it to a temporary location, then try to open it (perhaps with `sqlite3_open()`, but hopefully you're using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) or similar) and if that fails, conclude that the data is invalid.

Comment: yes, I'm going that (saving NSData and then opening the file) and if fails that means correct file not downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will help u to check extension.

```
NSString *url = @"http://example.com/mydatabase.bdx";
if([url hasSuffix:@".db"])
NSData *dbfile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```